# Basic second timer implementation

Tags: java, android

I am very new to the android platform thus java so i have a pretty basic question i am trying to make a simple second timer so here is the code i have written. I don't know why but the method run never gets executed:

```
        Timer tmr = new Timer();
        tmr.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLoading);
                counter++;
                txt.setText(counter);

            }

        }, 1000);
```

LE : actually it looks like it executing but the GUI doesn't get updated ... why ?

Comment: your code would only run once, you need to add a period after the delay in the schedule method.

Comment: oh also counter is a integer and if you do txt.setText(integer) it looks for the resource instead of casting it. You need to do String.valueOf(++counter);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Timer like that creates a new Thread, and updating the GUI from a thread which is not the main thread is not a good idea.
A better approach is the one reported in this link: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I guess that is because you are not working in your UI thread. Read about UI threads [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

You might want to consider using AsyncTask that takes care of all the UI thread syncronisation stuff ;)

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this

```
Timer tmr = new Timer();
        tmr.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.w("this", "is 1");
            }

        },1000, 1000);
```